# What does "nuclear-hardened" mean?

Tags: meaning

From the book [What If?](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=tgZIBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA3&lpg=PA3&dq=the+flying+debris+would+pulverize&source=bl&ots=RnfQ9fzOOJ&sig=Wz3r1CQEnUvwDz0OtoeulZWp14U&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=the%20flying%20debris%20would%20pulverize&f=false) of XKCD when talking about super strong winds:

> The flying debris would pulverize anything that wasn't **nuclear-hardened**.

[image: image description]

What does *nuclear-hardened* mean? The closest result from Google for this term is [Radiation hardening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_hardening). But *radiation hardening* simply means making a device withstand-able in high radiation environment. The context doesn't mention anything about radiation, or radiation wind (if it even exists), just air wind.

So what does nuclear-hardened mean?

Comment: Your answer is in the comic itself. Depleted Uranium is high density and is being used to create armor plating. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depleted_uranium

Comment: I believe *nuclear-hardened* means hardened to withstand an attack by a nuclear weapon - including not only the radiation, but also the explosion.

Comment: Let's swap phasing in the quote and in your defintion:  The flying debris would pulverize anything that wasn't radiation-hardened.  But nuclear hardening simply means making a device withstand-able [sic] in [a] high nuclear [fallout] environment.  Does that help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nuclear hardened means able to withstand the nearby detonation of a nuclear device.  I used to work* in such a building, part of the USAF SAGE program of the 1950s & 60s: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-Automatic_Ground_Environment  The walls & floors were about 2-3 ft of reinforced concrete, intended to withstand a nuclear detonation on the airfield about 1/4 mile away.

*Not when it was in active military use, but some decades later, when it had been converted to an academic research facility.